# Add multiple records to database on product purchase

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

**Edit #1**

Here is what I am trying in the payments controller to create the CourseModulesUser

```
CourseModules.count do
  CourseModulesUser.create.times(
    course_module_id: @course_module_id,
    courses_user_id: @courses_user_id,
    complete: false
  )
end
```

I have a course modules but in order to create the users I need to be able to count the modules for the course bought and then create the records in the CourseModulesUser grabbing the course_user_id and also the course_module_id.

[image]

**Orginal Question**

Scenario:

I have courses and modules, and when a user purchases the course a user gets created for that course (kind of like an enrollment), however, when the course gets purchased I also want the modules to go into a separate table taking in the course_module_id and the courses_user_id.

However, there are multiple modules per course,

Here is the payments controller

```
class PaymentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def create
    token = params[:stripeToken]
    @course = Course.find(params[:course_id])
    @user = current_user

    begin
      charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
        amount: (@course.price*100).to_i,
        currency: "gbp",
        source: token,
        description: params[:stripeEmail],
        receipt_email: params[:stripeEmail]
      )

      if charge.paid
        Order.create(
          stripe_id: charge.id,
          course_id: @course.id,
          user_id: @user.id,
          total: @course.price,
          card_last4: charge.source.last4,
          card_type: charge.source.brand,
          card_exp_month: charge.source.exp_month,
          card_exp_year: charge.source.exp_year
        )

        CoursesUser.create(
          course_id: @course.id,
          user_id: @user.id,
          complete: false
        )

        flash[:success] = "Your payment was processed successfully"
      end

    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      body = e.json_body
      err = body[:error]
      flash[:error] = "Unfortunately, there was an error processing your payment: #{err[:message]}"
    end

    redirect_to course_path(@course)
  end
end
```

Here is where I have the course user being created

```
CoursesUser.create(
  course_id: @course.id,
  user_id: @user.id,
  complete: false
)
```

and this works

[image]

But I have a separate table for course_modules_users

[image]

So let's say for example I have a course with two modules, and a course with the id of 1 and a user with the id of 1 I would ideally have something like this

```
id  course_module_id   courses_user_id   complete
1   1                  1                 false
2   2                  1                 false
```

So when a user purchases the course both modules should have records created in this table.

Here is what I have for the model

```
class CourseModulesUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :course_module
  belongs_to :courses_user

  after_update :update_courses_user, if: :completed?

  def siblings
    self.class.where(courses_user_id: self.courses_user_id)
  end

  def completed!
    self.update_attributes(complete: true)
  end

  def completed?
    siblings.all?(&:complete?)
  end

  def update_courses_user
    self.courses_user.completed!
  end
end
```

But I assume this is just a simple edit to the PaymentsController.

Comment: Please include in your question the callback for the `CoursesUser` which creates the CourseModulesUsers

Comment: Please see edit #1 @Rodrigo hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways that I could do this depending on how and when do I want the records for the `CourseModelUser` to be created:

1. I want the records to be created along with the creation of `CourseUser` (if `CourseUser` doesn't get created due to any reason then `CourseModuleUser` shouldn't get created as well). This code goes along with the `CourseUser` creation in your payments controller.

   ```
   ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
     CoursesUser.create(
       course_id: @course.id,
       user_id: @user.id,
       complete: false
     )
     module_ids = CourseModule.where(course_id: @course.id).pluck(:id)
     module_ids.each do |module_id|
     CourseModuleUser.create(
       course_module_id: module_id,
       courses_user_id: @user.id,
       completed: false
     )
     end
   end
   ```
2. I just want the `CourseModuleUser` to be created after the creation of `CourseUser` model. This code goes inside the `CourseUser` model.

   ```
   after_commit :create_couser_module_user

   def create_module_user
     module_ids = CourseModule.where(course_id: self.course_id).pluck(:id)
     module_ids.each do |module_id|
     CourseModuleUser.create(
       course_module_id: module_id,
       courses_user_id: self.id,
       completed: false
     )
   end
   ```

Note: The answer assumes you've the following model structure:

```
class Course
  ..
  has_many :course_modules
  ..
end

class CourseModule
  ..
  belongs_to :course
  ..
end
```

Comment: That's spot on, thank you.

Would it be possible for you to example option one further so I can understand it more?